# Sum of reciprocals of odd squares and integral of $\log(x)/(1-x^2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to prove that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(x))}{1-x^2}\,dx=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}. $

I know that the RHS is equal to $-\frac{\pi^2}{8} $.

Additionally, I have tried to make the substitution $x=\sin(u)$ to the integral, which leaves with $\int_{u=0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\log(\sin(x))}{\cos(x)}\,dx $ but I can't seem to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3):

Using partial fraction expansion reveals

$$\frac1{1-x^2}=\frac12\left(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac1{1+x}\right)$$

---

Next using the Taylor series for $\log(x)$ and owing to uniform convergence, we can integrate term by term to arrive at

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)}{1-x}\,dx&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\int_0^1 \frac{(x-1)^{n-1}}{n}\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^2}\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

Next, using integration by parts on the integral $\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)}{1+x}\,dx$ we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)}{1+x}\,dx&=-\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}}{n}\,dx\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}\tag2
\end{align}$$

---

Finally, adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ and dividing by $2$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)}{1-x^2}\,dx&=-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1+(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}\right)\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^2}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Hi Mark ! One (more) good answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hi Calude! Thank you.  And Happy Holidays!!

Answer (score 3):

Anothe solution
$$I=\int\frac{\log(x)}{1-x^2}\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int x^{2n}\log(x)\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2 n+1} ((2 n+1) \log (x)-1)}{(2 n+1)^2}$$

Using the bounds, the result.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following integral parametrised by $a$,

$$
I(a) =\int_0^1 \frac{x^a}{1-x^2} d x =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 x^{2 n+a} d x= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n+a+1}
$$
Then we can find the exact value of
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =I^{\prime}(0) \\
& =-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 n+1)^2} \\
& =-\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 n)^2}\right] \\
& =-\frac{3}{4} \zeta(2) \\
& =-\frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{6} \\
& =-\frac{\pi^2}{8}
\end{aligned}
$$