# How can I evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\cos(x)}dx$ without using special functions?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to evaluate $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\cos(x)}dx$$
but I couldn't really get it to work,
I know that $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\sin(x))dx =-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2)$ which I could prove I tried to use that fact to simplify the integral to a be similar to this, so I expected $\ln(2)$ to be in the answer  as a connection between the two problems
but when I checked wolfram alpha the answer seem to not have $\ln(2)$(the answer is $-\frac{\pi^2}{8}$)

I haven't learn about special functions like beta function yet, so I want a proof without special functions.

Comment: Do you know anything about Beta function? One way to evaluate this integral is :derivative of Beta function.

Comment: @OnTheWay ,no I don't know anything about it or any other special functions btw how can I learn about them ,do you have any good sources (books)to learn about special functions? and what course they are part of ?

Comment: @Ahmed If your Interested to learn that, Plz follow The famous book "Almost impossible Intergals" there is a famous integral on the very beginning of the book fractional part of x/y. y/z. z/x. What I am trying to say you will get that after buying that book. Warning is that initially you cannot solve that question but after completing the whole book you can Actually Solve it which involves zeta function and some logs of the not only three variable such integrals but also I recommend your o try, n variable such fractional quanitity.

Comment: Would this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3924114/1104384

Comment: Use $x=\sin^{-1}(t)$ to face a simple integral

Comment: @Bruno B yes it does , now should I delete the question ?

Comment: No you shouldn't delete it.

Comment: How about an evaluation by the residue theorem? (Hint: set $z=-\ln\sin x$, use the fact the integrand's now even to write the result in terms of an integral over $\Bbb R$, then evaluate it by integrating $\frac{z^2e^{-z}}{1-e^{-2z}}$ around a rectangular contour with long edges $\Im z=\pm\pi$ by the semi-residue lemma.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an elementary evaluation, let
$ I(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\ln(1-\sin^2a\cos^2 x)}{2\cos x}dx$.
Then
\begin{align}
I’(a)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin a \cos a\cos x}{\sin^2a\cos^2 x-1}dx= \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{-\cot a}{\cot^2a+\sin^2 x} d(\sin x) =-a
\end{align}
and
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\cos x}dx
=I(\frac\pi2)= -\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}a\ da=-\frac{\pi^2}8
$$

Comment: Magical parametric integral!  How to think about it?

Answer (score 4):

Enforce the substitution $x\mapsto \arcsin(x)$, we find that

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\log(\sin(x))}{\cos(x)}\,dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)}{1-x^2}\,dx\tag1$$

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3924114/sum-of-reciprocals-of-odd-squares-and-integral-of-logx-1-x2/3924146#3924146), I showed that the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ can be expressed as

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)}{1-x^2}\,dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(2n-1)^2}$$

Given the solution of the Basel problem, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(2n-1)^2}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1{(2n)^2}-\frac1{n^2}\right)\\\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}{8}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!